# Java - how to validate following input format 'operand operator operand' (e.g. 1.4 * 5)

Tags: java, regex, format, inputformatter

I'm breaking my head trying to figure out what is wrong in my code.
I'm asking the user to insert the following format:

```
LeftOperand operator RightOperand
```

Where:

- LeftOperand - can be any int or float number
- operator - can be +, -, * or /
- RightOperand - can be any int or float number

I searched and found few regular expressions but they all doesn't seems to work for me, as anything besides the following: `3 +/-/*// 5` returns an error.
Should be valid:

- 1 + 3
- 1 / 4
- 1.3 - 4
- 4 - 5.3
- 123 * 3434
- 12.34 * 485

but in fact only those are valid while the rest return error:

- 1 + 3 - correct
- 1 / 4 - correct
- 1.3 - 4 - error
- 4 - 5.3 - error
- 123 * 3434 - error
- 12.34 * 485 - error

I'm currently using the following regex in my code:

```
"[((\\d+\\.?\\d*)|(\\.\\d+))] [+,\\-,*,/] [((\\d+\\.?\\d*)|(\\.\\d+))]"
```

Tried all kind of regex, but none seems to work, and I just don't know what am I doing wrong:

```
[[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]] [+,\-,*,/] [[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]]
```

This is my client code:

```
private static final int SERVER_PORT = 8080;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "localhost";
private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private static final String regex = "[((\\d+\\.?\\d*)|(\\.\\d+))] [+,\\-,*,/] [((\\d+\\.?\\d*)|(\\.\\d+))]";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Step 1: Open the socket connection
    Socket serverSocket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);

    // Step 2: Communication-get the input and output stream
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());

    //Run until Client decide to disconnect using the exit phrase
    while (true) {
        // Step 3: Enter the equation in the form -
        // "operand1 operation operand2"
        System.out.print("Enter the equation in the form: ");
        System.out.println("'operand operator operand'");

        String input = sc.nextLine();
        // Step 4: Checking the condition to stop the client
        if (input.equals("exit"))
            break;

        //Step 4: Check the validity of the input and
        // return error message when needed
        if (input.matches(regex)) {
            System.out.println("Expression is correct: " + input);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Expression is incorrect, please try again: ");
            continue;
        }

        // Step 5: send the equation to server
        dos.writeUTF(input);

        // Step 6: wait till request is processed and sent back to client
        String ans = dis.readUTF();
        // Step 7: print the response to the console
        System.out.println("Answer=" + Double.parseDouble(ans));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `[+*/-]` (Minus at begin or end or escaped (otherwise it would be a range like `a-z`). Also you might do negative numbers as `(-?\\d...`. And instead of the space `\\s*`.

Comment: Hi @JoopEgen, sorry, but didn't get you. What do I need to do in order to get the regular expression to except also float and "big numbers" and not only one char int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final String NUM = "(-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?)";
private static final String OP = "([-+*/])"; // Minus at begin to avoid confusion with range like a-z.
private static final String WHITESPACE = "\\s*";
private static final String regex = NUM + WHITESPACE + OP + WHITESPACE + NUM;
```

Note:

- `$1` corresponds with the first number
- `$3` corresponds with the operator
- `$4` corresponds with the second number
- `(...)` is a *group* ($1, $2, ...; $0 is all)
- `[...]` is a character set, one char match
- `X?` X optional
- `X*` X 0 or more times
- `X+` X 1 or more times
- `\\s` space, tab
- `\\d` digit

Comment: Thanks @Joop Eggen. Indeed above is much better now. 
But I do face an issue, that when trying the following: 123 +2 the: 

if(input.matches(regex)) {
                System.out.println("Expression is correct: " + input);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Expression is incorrect, please try again: ");
                continue;
            }

Find it correct, although it is not.
Do you know why?

Actually, it seems as if it doesn't pay any attention to the WHITESPACE, and any combination a following: 
1+2
1 /34.4
etc. 
Is valid for it

Comment: Never mind. I found the issue. I changed the 

private static final String WHITESPACE = "\\s*";

To be: 

private static final String WHITESPACE = "\\s+";

And now it much better. 
Appreciate your help :)